# joining two simple schema in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2

Is there any way of joining two simple schema at the same level. I mean:

```
var a = new SimpleSchema({
    name:
        type: String
});

var b = new SimpleSchema({
    email:
        type: String
});

//required result c=a+b
c = new SimpleSchema({
     name:
         type: String
     email:
         type: String
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [`SimpleSchema` docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#combining-simpleschemas), you can use the `SimpleSchema` constructor syntax along with an array :

```
var c = new SimpleSchema([a, b]);
```